# deep link with xamarin forms android not worked

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deep-linking

I tried to implement support for deep links in Xamarin forms for Android. but unable to do it so far. Can anyone help me?

what i done

1. install nuget package Xamarin.Forms.AppLinks
   [image]

2).use intent filter as below and init AppLinks after forms.init
[image]

3).tried to browse wori://example.com/test with android simulator's browser

[image]

Comment: What instructions did you follow to do this? I've never used deep links myself, but googling Android docs that talk about it, you have to set something up, on a web domain, for these links to work. If you type the url shown into a browser, you will also get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. Because the internet attempts to find "wori". But there is no such internet domain.

Comment: You need to check the prerequisites first in the link and then follow the steps in the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking You could download the source file from the link below for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/deeplinking/